# Wordpress : Call to a member function generate_cart_id() in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a project hving cart task with API but facing some issues, see the code below :

```
$string = $woocommerce->cart->generate_cart_id( $product_id, 0, array(), array());
```

I have Cocart plugin but when I deactive the cocart plugin, it shows this error given below. So my code only works with Cocart plugin but I am surprised it has nothing related with that plugin, see error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function
>   generate_cart_id() on null in
>   /wp-content/themes/testtheme-child/functions.php:117 Stack trace:

As I know this is default function of Woocommerce and has no role with Cocart plugin But still getting the same error.

Please help if you can. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have pro version of cocart plugin?

Comment: Yes I am using pro version

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in that way, change  code given below:

```
$variation_id   = 0;
$variations = 0;

$variation      = array();
$cart_item_data = array();

$product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
$stock = $product->get_stock_quantity();

$array_prod = array( 'product_id'=>$product_id, 'uid'=>$userid, 'variation_id'=>$variation_id, 'variation'=>$variation, 'stock'=>$stock);

$string = md5(serialize($array_prod));

$product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
```